# Convert matrix to a list of lists

Tags: r, list, matrix

Simple question.

I have a `matrix`:

```
my.mat <- matrix(c(1,5,2,6),nrow=2,ncol=2)
```

Which I want to convert to a `list` of `lists` by rows, so the result of the example above is:

```
my.list <- list(list(1,2),list(5,6))
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
apply(my.mat, 1, as.list)

identical(my.list, apply(my.mat, 1, as.list))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `lapply`

```
lapply(1:NROW(my.mat), function(i) lapply(1:NCOL(my.mat), function(j) my.mat[i,j]))

identical(my.list, lapply(1:NROW(my.mat), function(i)
    lapply(1:NCOL(my.mat), function(j)
        my.mat[i,j])))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: A simplification of this (no nested loop) is `lapply(seq_len(nrow(my.mat)), function(x) as.list(my.mat[x,]))`.